# Got verbal permission to use "Senior" title in flat organization

Tags: manager, job-description, title

I work in the US as a software engineer. There are other developers here who are sometimes referred to as "Senior" engineers. I've been doing well at my job, and have developed a few important applications independently with no guidance, so I asked my manager for a promotion, specifically asking if I could become a "Senior Software Engineer".

Then, about a week ago, I had a performance review, which was very positive. My manager then told me that we actually have a flat organizational structure, and the older "Senior" engineers are just referred to as "Software Engineer" in their actual contracts.  Despite this, he gave me permission to use the title and specifically mentioned I could put it on LinkedIn.

I'm not planning on leaving the company anytime soon, but I'm wondering is something like this OK to put on my resume? It feels like lying. But I also know that my achievements would back up the title, and I got permission. At the same time, I'm worried about this permission being forgotten, or what might happen if my relationship with the manager sours, or if they leave the company. I also don't want to press the issue too hard because they might think I want to leave.

Am I thinking way too hard about this? Is it OK to use this title? Thanks for reading.

EDIT: Based on some comments I thought I'd add that I did get a pay raise and I've mentored a junior employee alone in the past. But this doesn't really change my feeling that it may be dishonest to use the title

Comment: Your LinkedIn, ok. Your resume, no. If a future employer does a simple employment check, they're going to call your HR, not your manager. You need to get this formally accepted by HR. Maybe try to get a nice pay raise as well.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk I'm thinking that I will notify HR of the update and try to get a written confirmation in an email, but I'm not certain that they would be willing to actually alter the contract.  Would this be acceptable?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

> Am I thinking way too hard about this? Is it OK to use this title?

Yes, because you got permission to use it.

Be aware that the meaning of titles and the concrete responsibilities that come with it are not uniformly defined across companies. Not at all.

Therefore, as you have been allowed to *use* the title, the question is: What does it mean *in your particular workplace*?

> we actually have a flat organizational structure

The structure can be as flat as you wish, but that does not change the fact that different people come with different levels of professional experience. In this situation, "senior" simply denotes a higher level of skills, not a higher "rank" in some kind of hierarchy.

*For what it's worth, this is a meaning I know even from workplaces without a flat hierarchy. "Senior" does not imply any kind of leading position, it just denotes a greater experience.*

So, on profiles like LinkedIn, try to briefly outline your responsibilities and topics. There are different ways in which these can reflect the title of "senior", and I think the assumption others will think you are lying about the title is unfounded if this outline reasonably reflects a "senior level", even if this happens by other factors than by being "above" someone else in a hierarchy.

Comment: "Senior" usually implies mentoring "junior" people.

Comment: As lead, "senior" to me means "can be given a task knowing it will be completed. The right questions will be asked and the quality will be sufficient".

Comment: @SimonRichter: Sure, that evolves naturally, because those who know less tend to turn to those who know more for guidance. But either that comes without any *general* understanding that seniors can assign tasks to juniors, or maybe the hierarchy is not actually as flat as the employer advertises.

Comment: @SimonRichter but mentoring is not supervising, and can be undertaken with or without a different title. In my industry days, as a "graduate engineer", "design engineer", and "senior design engineer" I reported to the same "principle systems designer" (who reported to the "design manager"). I was hardware but software had the same structure.  Once I had enough experience I gained project leadership and mentoring responsibilities, but never had anyone reporting to me (though some "seniors" did in bigger teams, usually supervising new hires/apprentices).

Comment: Especially with "Senior software engineer" the senior is absolutely not uniformly defined and varies very very wildly

Comment: @SimonRichter: I've seen many cases of Senior defined as "has more than x years of experience." So YMMV and the hiring teams probably know this already.

Comment: +1 For me, "senior" has meant little more than "we know some people care about titles and we really want Todd to take this job, so we'll call him 'senior' to recognize his many years of experience and further entice him to accept the position, even though he'll be paid the same or less than some of his peers." Not that I don't appreciate it - it does look good on a resume.

Comment: As someone occasionally involved in recruitment, I agree that job titles are largely irrelevant... a "Lead Engineer" might be a twenty year veteran, or it might be someone who dropped out of college last year to join a friend's startup. What matters is whether you can convince a recruiter that you can do the job you're applying for.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, i'd not use the title until I needed to (e.g.,if i was moving company/department). What are you actually achieving in doing so?

As you stated, you work in a flat hierarchy so you will be introducing an implied senior scale. If i was in this group of peers i'd be somewhat taken-aback.

On a side note, a previous company i worked at gave 'titles' out instead of pay-rises. Senior in your title is all well in good but not as good as 20% extra in your pay packet

Comment: Yeah I agree about not wanting to upset any peers.  For what it's worth, I got a pay raise and I've already been expected to mentor a new hire

Comment: The usefulness of using it when you're actually "awarded" it is that it provides a time scale of "time in position" as well as establishes the expectation within the peer group. In addition, while the position may not have fundamentally changed, by indicating the change with a point-in-time on a resume or bio (e.g. LinkedIn), it's easy to demonstrate a pattern of growth and change to future employers.

Answer (score 2):

Stephan Branczyk gave the best response in a comment but I will pick it up from there.  As somebody involved in hiring and firing, if I saw that your resume said your title was one thing and your HR department said it was another I would have some doubts about you going into an interview.

Perhaps you will interview well and overcome my concerns, but when given a choice between two otherwise equal candidates I will likely pick the candidate who doesn't inflate their resume.

Additionally, in a flat organization, don't you think your peers might get annoyed with you? Some of my colleagues pay attention to social media and if I were to inflate my title on Linked In I'd get called out.  Sure, it would be in the form of a jest, but not everyone would take it that way.

I don't see where you calling yourself a "senior" in your organization is going to help you.  Since your organization is flat that means there probably are no official "seniors" and your peers that are being called  senior by others are probably just being called that to imply they are reliable or perhaps have just been around the company for a long time.  It's a sign of respect.  You coming along and just bestowing that respect in yourself is not going to look good.

Comment: Typically, would you know what a candidates HR department said there title was, before an interview?

Comment: In my current organization, yes.  I don't think thats normal as most of the other companies I have worked for have NOT done that to my knowledge.  But we are handed candidates by the HR team here. (There are some exceptions.) Either way, it will likely come out.

Comment: Clarity, I mentioned this to a colleague and they reminded I am mostly involved in second interviews.  The notes I am looking at come from first interviews and HR combined.

Comment: "don't you think your peers might get annoyed with you?", yeah, this is  concern of mine, and something I'm also not sure about

Comment: What HR formally has you listed as and what your actual job title are rarely match up in my experience. In hiring I would assign 0 relevance to the job title they list on a reference.

Comment: I think you're being a bit accusatory here. The querent isn't bestowing the title on themselves. They requested the title, their manager deemed it was appropriate and then bestowed the title on them.

Comment: @Pyrotechnical I don't mean to be accusatory.  I was referring to the OPs remark, "specifically asking if I could become a 'Senior Software Engineer'."  The manager in question basically said "Sure. You can call yourself that even though that title doesn't exist in our company and your actual title is something else."

Comment: @SailingJudo You're assuming HR keeps things neatly updated and correctly keeps tab on everyones titles and positions (i.e.: did its job). I can attest that HR doesn't always do its job and those discrepancies happen _all the time_, specially with folks that stayed for quite a bit and changed titles a bunch on a single org.  A personal example: I was promoted four times on my previous job, with the proper ammends done on my contract. Yet, when my current employer called asking for a ref, they used the outdated data from their accounting system, which created a mess title-wise.

Answer (score 2):

IMO, it's totally OK. It would be good to get this in writing. Not immediately, as it could rub your manager the wrong way to get an "as we discussed..." email regarding a somewhat informal conversation. But hold off for the next month, then be on the lookout for an opportunity to bring it up organically, and use it to get some form of written confirmation.

I really don't believe this will go that far. When flat organizations insist that their former employees present themselves with their 'flat titles', so to speak, to non-flat prospective employers in the future... that's not a good look for that company. However, just to be safe, I would hold on to that email chain. My suggested steps would be:

1. Put the title on LinkedIn / your resume
2. If your current company's HR takes issue with the title listed, at some point in the future, tell the company you're interviewing with that you received verbal and written permission from your manager to use the 'senior' title on LinkedIn and similar contexts. I think it'd be both incredibly rare, and a sign that they're extremely red tape-oriented, for a company to view this explanation as inadequate- as long as you ensure that it's believed.
3. If the old company's HR continues to deny it, only use your copy of the written permission as an absolute last resort. Tell HR when the email was sent and which emails it was sent to/from, ask them to check their records, etc. If they steadfastly deny it, bring up the copy first to the old company's HR, and then (if necessary) to the new company. I am not a lawyer, so if you want to be triply sure of the legality of keeping a copy, run this by one. I can't imagine it'd be a long consultation with such a narrow scope and specific facts.

I don't quite understand why other answers claim that you're introducing a senior pay scale when others were already referred to as senior engineers, or that you're bestowing the title upon yourself. Regardless of the fact that you requested it, it's very clear that the manager is bestowing the title, not you. If your coworkers take issue with *you* over that, tell them that you discussed it with the manager. From that point on, they should raise their objections to the manager who gave you the green light.